# How can I get programatically the character, word or line under the cursor in OneNote 2013

Tags: accessibility, onenote

I am trying to get the  character, word,  line  under the cursor, or the selection in OneNote 2013. I am going to use these to send them to a screen reader program in order to extend OneNote accessibility to blind users.

Comment: Please provide more information. Screen readers have the functionality to read a paragraph, line, word or character built in. I didnt look up the accessiblity issues of OneNote, I don't think Microsoft can block those functions. If you are talking about NVDA, I know it has a number of issues for programs, so it would be better to file a bug report to NVDA.

Comment: I am a blind user and I use the screen reader JAWS for Windows version 15.0. I am trying to access the text in OneNote 2013.

Comment: In OneNote 2010  JAWS for Windows and NVDA can read the character, word or line under the cursor when I move it with arrow or ctrl+arrow keys.

Comment: I still am not following. Your last comment says you can read stuff via ctrl+arrows, so what is the issue?

Comment: In OneNote 2010 I can read by arrow or ctrl+arrow keys, but in OneNote 2013 I cannot.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't catch the difference in versions. My recommendation is to file a [bug report](http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/966655/Microsoft-Accessibility-Survey)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I send a bug report. But I still would like to know how to access selection or cursor movement functionality in OneNote.